# Alternative to make a circle with div

Tags: html, css

I've a div using css 3,i'm placing a circle but when i place objects,it is going out of circle because div is still there and it is rectangle.

Can i use some thing instead of div and make circle.My objective is i need a circle ,when i place objects ,it should not move out of circle.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8Bdpz/1/) ?

Comment: @Mr_Green:http://jsfiddle.net/8Bdpz/4/

Comment: what do you mean? you are showing the same code? @redasaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no actual way of making an element circular. You can make it **look** circular using the well-known `border-radius` 'trick'.

To create the effect that the the text/contents of the `div` are only inside the borders of the circle, you can make sure it's filled within the largest square contained in the circle, using `padding`. Here's a visual illustration:

[image: Largest square in circle]

Here's a demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/WaTHz/).

HTML:

```
<div>
   Glee is awesome! Glee!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Edit:** for images, you have two cases:

- You want the `div` to have a circular background. In this case, use the `background-clip: padding-box;` property (you need vendor-prefixed versions for this to work). Here's a demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/3FSqs/).
- You have an `img` tag inside your `div` -- you can use the prior method.

Comment: @redasaw There's no way to achieve that -- there are no actual "circular" elements even in HTML5/CSS3. The best you can do is the approximation that I explained above.

Comment: @redasaw Can you rephrase what you mean? What's wrong with the jsFiddle you provided?

Comment: :I fixed it,thanks but how do i move the border.In my code the whole oval is towards left,i want to move it and also decrease the size of oval.

Comment: @redasaw To change the oval's position, just change the `margin-left` and the `margin-top` values. To change its size, change the `width` and `height`. Here's an example: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/kjsGd/).

Comment: :Fixed this also but have a big problem,i've a for loop so oval is coming for each loop.if loop run six times,six loops are coming,how do i fix this.I appreciate your help.

Comment: @redasaw What exactly is the `for` loop supposed to do?

Comment: @redasaw:I will have 300 images so i need a for loop.

Comment: @redasaw Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17289/discussion-between-abody97-and-redasaw)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a div with a border-radius equal to it's sides then you should have what you're looking for.

[Creating Circular div for CSS3 compatible browsers](http://anvilstudios.co.za/blog/css/creating-circular-for-css3-compatible-browsers/)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 there is an element called canvas. It can be used to draw, using javascript, and therefore also for animation. This might help you, if you only want to draw. Else you could go with the z-index property in css

Answer (score 0):

create a div and give it border-radius

```
   width: 230px;
   height: 230px;
   border-radius: 165px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 165px;
   -moz-border-radius: 165px;
```